# WP8 Listbox Loaded MVVM

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, listbox

I'm making a WP8 application using the MVVM patern (Caliburn.Micro).

I'm using a ListBox Named ProgramsList and I want to do something when Loaded.

```
<ListBox Name="ProgamsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Loaded="">
```

When not using the MVVM patern I could use the automatic generated Event handler.

How can I do this the right way using the MVVM patern?

Answer (score 2):

```
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"

<ListBox Name="ProgamsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>        
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>


    public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the SplashScreenViewModel class.
            /// </summary>
            public SplashScreenViewModel()
            {
                LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(toDoSomehing);
            }

    private void toDoSomething(){
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands to expose your logic from the ViewModel an then use behaviors, for example: http://metroeventtocommand.codeplex.com/

If that doesn't fit your needs, you can always use an event handler and call the command from there.